# How to avoid $\sigma=0$ of the test set in a k-fold cross validation of a binary data set

Tags: cross-validation, binary-data

Given an explanatory data matrix **X** (with n x p dimensions) with binary data (e.g. SNPs) and a response data matrix **Y** (n x q) (e.g. gene expression data).

The *k-fold cross validation* of a binary data matrix (values of 0s and 1s from a SNP dataset) causing the *standard deviation* ($\sigma$) = 0 in many columns in the training set. This leads to problems when later I wish to scale the given training set. My question is how to overcome this?

Here is a representation of the problem in R.

```
set.seed(7959559)

#number of rows
n = 100
#number of X columns
p = 10^5
#number of Y columns
q = 10^3

#create X and Y matrices
X <- matrix(rbinom(n*p,1,0.02),n,p)
Y <- matrix(rnorm(n*q,0,1),n,q)

#print dimensions of X and Y
print(dim(X));print(dim(Y))

#throw away columns with SD = 0
X <- X[,apply(X,2,sd)>0]
Y <- Y[,apply(Y,2,sd)>0]

#print dimensions of X and Y
print(dim(X));print(dim(Y))


#split up sets to cross-validate
k = 10

#the rowns to be sampled for the test sets
to_sample <- sample(n,n/k)

#create training and test sets for X and Y
X.training  <- X[setdiff(1:n,to_sample),]
X.test      <- X[to_sample,]
Y.training  <- Y[setdiff(1:n,to_sample),]
Y.test      <- Y[to_sample,]

#scale X
X.test.n <- scale(X.test)
#remove columns from X set with sd=0
X.test.n <- X.test[,apply(X.test,2,sd)>0]


dim(X.test)
dim(X.test.n)
```